# Can ECB be restricted to "take over" only the current buffer when it's activated?

Tags: r, emacs, ess, emacs-ecb

From the get go: sorry if I'm not using the proper emacs terminology -- I'm relatively wet behind the ears in the emacs world.

Most of my work in emacs is for programming R, and I'm using [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) and [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net) to do so quite happily. I'd like to build a custom ECB layout which uses the entire bottom of the screen as my R console, while putting some ECB-specific buffers on the left.

Using [ECB-esque layout diagrams](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/docs/Changing-the-ECB_002dlayout.html), I'd like my layout to look like pretty much exactly like "left13", except I'd like the entirety of the "compilation" buffer to be my running R console (or any shell, for that matter):

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|              |                                      |
|              |                                      |
|              |                                      |
|              |                                      |
|              |                                      |
|              |                                      |
|              |                                      |
| Directories  |                 Edit                 |
|              |                                      |
|              |                                      |
|              |                                      |
|              |                                      |
|              |                                      |
|              |                                      |
|              |                                      |
-------------------------------------------------------
|                                                     |
|                    R Console                        |
|                                                     |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

If I can just split my buffer in two (vertically), then call `ecb-activate` from the top buffer (and not allow it to touch my bottom buffer), I'm imagining it could work (hence the subject of my question).

That doesn't work, though, and I don't know how to get an entier "bottom pane" out of a layout to work in the way I like using trying to use ECB's customize layout functionality.

Does anybody know if/how I can do this?

Comment: Try emailing Marc Schwartz directly -- he is a happy emacs, ess, ecb (or was it cedet?) power user. I still limit myself to Emacs + ESS because I couldn't quite work things out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: No.

**Longer answer**: Unfortunately, ECB completely takes over Emacs "window" management at a very low level.  So it's all or nothing. You can't comfortably combine it with regular window splitting.  What you might be able to do, is to [adjust the layout](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/docs/Creating-a-new-ECB-layout.html) ECB gives you or to [program a custom layout](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/docs/The-layout-engine.html).  (Some assembly required.)

Comment: Intersting. Yeah, I gave up on this for now and just started to simply open my r console into a new frame (aka window) which I think works ok so long as I'm in GUI mode